# Auto-populate a sample article/post in user account on signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a Rails app where users can write a blog post. It can take a simple title and description.

But the feature I would like to have is that when a user signs up for the app their account will already have a sample post inside of their account so they can get an idea of how a blog post can look like and the features they have.

Any ideas or other stackoverflow questions answering how I can have a post already populated in users account on signup?

Comment: Usually you just insert a sample post into the database at the same time you're inserting the new user record as well.

Comment: `@brand_new_user.posts.create(title: ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`callback`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) `after_create`, which fired after records has been created(only once). Here is some example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  after_create do
    posts.create(title: 'Your new article')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a application doing something similar. I came from the school of fat model so my account model looks like this:

```
#app/models/account.rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  after_create :seed_account
  ...
  private 
  def seed_account
     ...
     posts.create(...)
     ...
  end
end
```

I hope that this helps.
This way when a new account is created no mater if from the console or api  or ui your account would always be seeded with its defaults